# MySQL index scan sort not working

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

I'm reading *High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, and Replication* by Schwartz, Zaitsev & Tkachenko (3rd edition, Oreilly). It's a great book so far. However, I came across an inconsistency in [Chapter 5 on page 183](http://books.google.com/books?id=IagfgRiKWd4C&lpg=PA183&ots=wYf3o0SwDm&dq=%22WHERE%20rental_date%20%3E%20%272005-05-25%27%20ORDER%20BY%20rental_date,%20inventory_id;%22&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q=%22WHERE%20rental_date%20%3E%20%272005-05-25%27%20ORDER%20BY%20rental_date,%20inventory_id;%22&f=false) (sorry for the long link. Google Books wouldn't give me a better one). Using the "rental" table from the [Sakila sample database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/index.html), we perform a couple SELECT queries that are supposed to use the indexes for scanning and sorting results. On my MySQL 5.5 server, when I run the highlighted query shown on Google Books, it doesn't appear to be using the rental_date index like expected.

Was this a mistake in the book, a difference between MySQL versions, etc?

The relevant table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE rental (
  `rental_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rental_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `inventory_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (rental_id),
  UNIQUE KEY rental_date (rental_date,inventory_id,customer_id),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the query in question, plus result I'm getting:

```
> EXPLAIN SELECT rental_id, staff_id FROM sakila.rental WHERE rental_date > '2005-05-25' ORDER BY rental_date, inventory_id\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: rental
         type: ALL
possible_keys: rental_date
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 16338
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is the '\G' at the end of the select something normal?

Comment: @Sebas \G returns the query result in this format, rather than as a table like ; would give you.

Comment: The '\G' modifier just formats the output in a list. You can replace it with the traditional semicolon. It will just change the formatting.

Comment: what happens if you use `WHERE rental_date > STR_TO_DATE('2005-05-25', '%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: I bet it will use the index if you change (only the SELECT) to: `SELECT rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id`

Comment: @Sebas Nothing extra seems to happen, which makes sense since I think '2005-05-25' is understood as a native datetime, not a string.

Comment: @ypercude It does indeed. It will even use it with SELECT rental_id (the primary key is included in all indexes silently, isn't it?). The inclusion of staff_id seems to be what stops it from using the key. Why, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely due to minor variations in the optimizer between versions. MySQL has determined that it will *likely* be faster to do a full table scan than to read a large amount of rows from the index. Anything above about 10% of the rows usually triggers that behavior.

See: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/

Comment: yes this is correct but in this case there's no way it would go faster with a FTS...

Comment: Why does that blog post show possible_keys as null? In my case, possible_keys correctly shows the rental_date key. This makes me think these two scenarios differ.

Comment: I linked to the wrong blog post by mistake. Here is another blog post that discusses the issue:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using InnoDB.  Change the engine to use MyISAM.  `alter table rental engine=myisam;`.

Comment: The rental table uses foreign keys (not shown in the partial table structure I showed), which MyISAM doesn't support. Though I think you're right that it would operate as expected on MyISAM. From [this article](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb), `...when "Using index" would be useful on the PRIMARY KEY, MyISAM would do an "index scan", yet InnoDB effectively has to do a "table scan"`.